# Constant line spacing on one side using reledpar

Tags: line-spacing, reledmac, reledpar, parallel-texts

I'm using reledpar pages option to have a text on left side, and commentary on the right side.

I have two problems:

1. having a title at the beginning of the right side affects the left side page, less text appears on left side because there is less text on the right I guess. Is it possible to unmatch right and left side? (I also tried with `pstart[chapter{name}]`, but it's even worse).
2. Probably for the same reason, I cannot have the first left page to appear after the right one, even if I add a blank page with `\clearpage\null\newpage`.
3. I want to have a particular linespread on the leftside, I tried with `\pstart[\linespread{1.5}\selectfont]`, it works but only on the first leftside page, not on the other ones.

Here is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\numberlinefalse
\begin{document}
\begin{pages}
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                \chapter{Some text taking space on the page, like a lot of space, leaving low space for the text, just a very long title, nothing to see here}
                \lipsum[21-40]
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside} 
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart[\linespread{1.5}\selectfont]
                \clearpage\null\newpage
                \lipsum[81-100]
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to change those things?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Unfortunatly, reledpar is conceived to have the same line spacing between left and right page. You could open a new issue to ask for new feature, but I have no time yet. I think, in any case, that you should look on the synchronisation option of reledpar (in the handbook)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think it is just not the right tool for what I wanted to do. I actually gave up doing it this way, as no tool seemed designed for it.